# Azure Web App VNet Integration - UNC path not accessible

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have a Azure Web App which is integrated to a VPN that has S2S configured and working.

When I try to access file in a UNC path providing IP (\IP\path) I am getting error message "Access to the path 'xxx' is denied. I am trying to pull some files in the on-prem UNC path to load to Azure DB in a WebJob.

I am able to access on-premise services using http followed by IP address, also I am able to send SMTP messages using the IP address of the on-prem SMTP server.

Can someone help me figure out what could be the issue here OR is it not supported?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Please let me know if any additional information needed. Btw, I created a VM in the VNET and it can access the UNC path.

*Update:* Code to access the path is within an Impersonation logic where I am passing the domain user details that has access to the path. Forgot to mention it in the initial post.

Comment: I think you have at least 2 issues here.  Firstly, the identity / account of the process that is executing the WebJob (the w3wp process?) doesn't have access to the UNC share.  Secondly, that account might not even have access to the network.  Can you switch this out and use an [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction)?  That way you can access it as a UNC-like share from the on-prem server, and programatically access it from the web job.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I have an Impersonation block within which the  access is happening/trying.  Process that drops the file is legacy and it is hard to change their out path. Queue trigger is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445).

This article mentions it under Restricted Outgoing Ports: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks Arora. From what I read on this article these ports are restricted and we cannot open it up right? Just making sure.

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT - Thank you! Just checking if there is any update?